# error while installing ros groovy on ubuntu 12.04 armel

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I want to install ROS groovy from source on ubuntu armel 12.04 according to this page http://wiki.ros.org/groovy/Installation/Source. I have download the ros-comm to  /ros_catkin_ws/src. Than  run :

```
$rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -yr
```

I get the following error

```
 executing command [sudo apt-get install -y python-rospkg]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-rospkg
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y python-catkin-pkg]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-catkin-pkg
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y sbcl]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sbcl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  sbcl-source sbcl-doc

E: Package 'sbcl' has no installation candidate
executing command [sudo apt-get install -y python-rosdep]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-rosdep
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y python-rospkg] failed
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y python-catkin-pkg] failed
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y sbcl] failed
  apt: command [sudo apt-get install -y python-rosdep] failed
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rospkg]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-catkin-pkg]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [sbcl]
  apt: Failed to detect successful installation of [python-rosdep]
```

In fact,  I have successfully installed  rospkg  , catkin-pkg  and   rosdep.
So,I install them again.

```
$sudo pip install rospkg catkin-pkg rosdep
```

I  got the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rospkg in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): catkin-pkg in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packs
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): rosdep in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Please help me to solve this problem. thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197187/error-while-installing-ros-groovy-on-ubuntu-12.04-armel/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosdep cannot detect the installation of packages through pip. You can ignore any errors for packages that are installed through pip (python-rospkg, python-rosdep and python-catkin-pkg).

There is no version of `sbcl` available for the armel version of Ubuntu, so you'll have to go through your ROS source tree and remove the packages that depend on sbcl. (probably roslisp and friends). You'll also want to remove any other packages that actually use sbcl, and edit the package.xml for ros_comm to remove the dependency on sbcl.

**PS**: I'm still going to recommend that you install an armhf version of Ubuntu instead of trying to make things work on armel. The armel packages perform poorly; you won't be able to run any interesting packages like navigation or use the OpenNI/Kinect drivers.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-11-13**:
Thank you ahendrix .Now the roscore can run succesfully on arm when I remove the roslisp. At the same time,I   am finding  an armhf version of Ubuntu,too.I want to try the boths way.